# C Program using structs What is going on?/Isn't working correctly

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently working on fixing a piece of code I've been working on for the past few weeks. Pretty much what this is supposed to do is generate a linked list of structs. Currently it generating nothing but I'm still working on the code. I could use any advice on how to implement the insert_ordered correctly. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc and rand
#include <stdio.h>

struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *Next_PCB ;
    int PID ;
} ;

struct PCB *ptr, *tmp ;
void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add) ;
void print_list(struct PCB *Head) ;

int main()
{
    int num_structs, i;

    ptr = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof (struct PCB)) ;
    ptr->Next_PCB = NULL;
    ptr->PID = rand()%20;

    num_structs = 10 + (rand() % 10) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num_structs ; i++)
    {tmp = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof(struct PCB)) ;
        tmp->PID = rand() % 20 ;
        tmp->Next_PCB = NULL ;

    insert_ordered(ptr, tmp);
    }
    print_list(ptr) ;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }



void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
    struct PCB* first;
    if ((Head == NULL) || ((Head)->PID >= Add->PID)){
            Add->Next_PCB= Head;
            Head = Add;
        }
    else{
            first = Head;
    }
    while ((first->Next_PCB != NULL) && (first->Next_PCB->PID < Add->PID))
    {
        first = first->Next_PCB;
    }
    Add->Next_PCB = first->Next_PCB;
    first->Next_PCB = Add;
}


void print_list(struct PCB *Head)
{
    tmp=(struct PCB *) malloc(sizeof(struct PCB));
    tmp=Head;

    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {

        printf("%d\n", tmp->PID);
        tmp=tmp->Next_PCB;

    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This code will now compile but I'm currently getting no output from the file.

Comment: You seem to understand it fine! The original is a skeleton for you to write two (probably recursive) linked-list processing functions, and you've had a go at that (in your "simplified" version). I take it they don't work? What's wrong with them? Can you debug it yourself?

Comment: What's wrong with his indenting?  I'm sure it makes perfect sense to him.  Open your mind :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan the post was edited before your comment. :-)

Comment: That isn't much of an improvement then - lol!

Comment: Surely you're joking Mr Dorgan!  I'm just trying to help the OP.  Chaotic indentation style is an efficient form of self-obfuscation. The compiler does not mind, and C-A-\ fixes it...

Comment: @ Rup I'm not very good at debugging I'm very new to programming in C currently I'm not quite sure whats wrong with the new simplified version it wont compile as it currently is though.

Comment: Sorry about the indenting I'm not used to this website.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 2):

in short, a struct is (in very brief layman's terms): a collection of data under the same name. [More info](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson7.html). Basically, you can store the values for all of your test scores (for example) under

```
struct test_scores {
    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    ...
}
```

Where you can set their values under `main` with

```
main() 
{
    struct test_scores Math;
    Math.test1 = 90;
    Math.test2 = 85;
    Math.test3 = 100;
}
```

(of course, with more code around them!) The `*` in the line `struct PCB *ptr, *tmp, *tcn;` indicates a [pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html) (and yes, I do quite like cprogramming.com! It's where I learned c++)

You do seem to have a handle on that stuff (was reading the comments showing up as I type this). What I think is confusing you, as it confused me for a long time (and admittedly, still does) is this line:

```
struct PCB *Next_PCB;
```

What this is, is a [linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html). A linked list is a setup you can use in c++ that lets you create several structs under a linked list (similar to how you can set several variables in a struct, just one level higher). The `*Next_PCB` is a pointer that would point to the next struct in the linked list. So, keeping with the test analogy, you could put all of your courses in one linked list. Instead of creating an individual struct for each course, i.e. `struct Math { int test1; }; struct Physics { int test1; };` you can simply create one struct `struct Courses { int test1; struct Courses *next; }`, and then, in the `main()` function, create the Math struct, and then create the Physics struct to make a linked list. (N.B. Check the source for a good example).

---

You seem to understand what you're doing, or simply getting lucky with your edits! To all the 'actual' c programmers, I know that I simplified things quite a bit! Am willing to step through more thoroughly than explaining how the structs and linked lists work if you still are having difficulties.

**Edit:** You commented saying it wouldn't compile after/just before I posted this, going to look through the code, try to help. **Edit 2.0:** And someone beat me to that. Oh well

Comment: Thank you very much thats very nice of you! I'm looking through your information right now and Its starting to make a lot more sense I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm going to start reworking mine but would you mind looking at my new simple version of the program if you have a second to see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Sure thing, I noticed that the line `void insert_ordered(struct PCB *Add)` does not contain an argument for the linked list you already have (`struct PCD *Head` in original code and @Michael Dorgen's) When you call `if (prt->Next_PCB == NULL)` it doesn't know what "prt" is and so can't compile. In Michael's he uses `Add->Next_PCB = Head; Head = Add;` to extend the linked list, and the `tcn` is for memory management (as explained in comments)

Comment: ok I've now got it returning the number 7. I've also changed a few things around in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and commented the above code and called out a few deficiencies and a ton of memory leaks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct PCB 
{
  struct PCB *Next_PCB;
  int PID;
};

struct PCB *ptr, *tmp, *tcn;

void insert_ordered(struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add);
void print_list(struct PCB *);

int main() 
{
  int num_structs, i;

  // Allocate memory for the PCB structure and setup it's pointers and data
  ptr=(struct PCB *) malloc(sizeof (struct PCB));
  ptr->Next_PCB=NULL;
  ptr->PID=rand() % 20;

  // Let's create between 10 and 19 structures
  num_structs=10 + (rand() % 10);
  for (i=0; i<num_structs; i++)
  {
    tmp = (struct PCB *) malloc(sizeof(struct PCB));
    tmp->PID=rand() % 20;
    tmp->Next_PCB = NULL;

    // Add these structures in order of their PID
    insert_ordered(ptr, tmp); 
  }

  // Print the result to screen
  print_list(ptr);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void insert_ordered(struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
  // Create a new structure, even though Add and Head already exist?

  tcn = (struct PCB*) malloc(sizeof(struct PCB));

  // If there is no Head, or if Head's PID is smaller than head's
  // value, make Add the new head.
  if (Head == NULL || Head->PID >= Add->PID)
  {
    Add->Next_PCB=Head;
    Head=Add;
  }
  else 
  {
    // Otherwise leak memory.
    tcn=Head;

    // Step through our list until we hit the end (Next_PCB == NULL)
    // Or the value we're adding is bigger than what is in the list.
    // Confusing as hell to swap from < and >= above on the Head check.
    while (tcn->Next_PCB != NULL && tcn->Next_PCB->PID < Add->PID)
    {
      tcn=tcn->Next_PCB;
    }

    // Point Add's next pointer to our current next pointer 
    // (Hope it isn't NULL because boom...)
    // And point the current list's Next to Add to complete list insertion.
    Add->Next_PCB=tcn->Next_PCB;
    tcn->Next_PCB=Add;
  }
}

void print_list(struct PCB *Head)
{
  // Malloc some memory and leak it just for the hell of it.
  tmp=(struct PCB *) malloc(sizeof(struct PCB));
  tmp=Head;

  // Step through the list and print IDs.
  while (tmp != NULL) 
  {
    printf("%d\n", tmp->PID);
    tmp=tmp->Next_PCB;
  }

  EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much I appreciate it! That was a huge help! I'll look it over and see what I can do with my own now.

Comment: In `print_list()` you allocate memory then immediately over write the pointer, so it can't be `free()`ed anyway.

Comment: Would you be willing to look through my newer code to see if something I've written is incorrect?